# Adjust multiple text items in composer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In composer I can select multiple items but if I change their attributes the change is only applied to the first item selected.

Example:

Select multiple text items using shift select (Mac OS X), change font colour or size. Change is only applied to the first item selected all others remain unchanged.

Is there away to apply changes to all, or the equivalent of paste attributes to text or set a character style globally?

Comment: I think they add text style in the style manager recently (3.10 or 3.12) did you check that ? ( It could also be only label style, if so you're out of luck)

Comment: I think this is just label from what I can see, but good tip

Comment: Just check in 3.12.0 and there is indeed a "Text format" tab in the style manager (along with a "label setting"). After a quick look I can't find a way to apply this text format to a composer label (and the setting of text format seem buggy) ; maybe this feature is still in development...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately afaik it isn't currently possible to change multiple items in the composer at once, regardless of whether they're text boxes, lines, map items...

The closest thing you can get is 'Copy format' in QGIS 3.12 which will let you copy and paste the type face, font size, style, and any underline. However it won't copy over colour - that has to be copied and pasted separately.

I think it would be great if this could be data-defined as well, say using a project variable or layout variable...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change color and fonts together by using PyQGIS for all selected items (if they are the same type, didn't document the other use case for this intent) with the following recipe.

You will need before running it in one go:

- to provide the layout "id"
- to set an "id" to the object you want to copy from in the layout
- to select graphically the objects you want to copy to in the layout

The idea about what you want to copy like in the styles on layer

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('demo-copy-style')

# You must set an "id" on the element you want to copy
copyfromthis = layout.itemById('copyfromthis')
fontcolorfrom = copyfromthis.fontColor()
fontfrom = copyfromthis.font()
familyfontfrom = fontfrom.family()
familyitalicfrom = fontfrom.italic()
familyboldfrom = fontfrom.bold()


# Select the blocks you want to copy to BEFORE running the following
if len(layout.selectedLayoutItems()) > 0:
    for item in layout.selectedLayoutItems():
        if type(copyfromthis) == type(item):
            # If you want new font styles of your own from scratch
            # newfont = QFont()
            # newfont.setFamily(familyfontfrom)
            # newfont.setItalic(familyitalicfrom)
            # newfont.setBold(familyboldfrom)
            # newfont.setPointSize(12)
            # item.setFont(newfont)
            # If you want to copy from the existing font
            item.setFont(fontfrom)
            item.setFontColor(fontcolorfrom)

layout.refresh()
```

The idea you mentioned would be more or less like the copy/paster styles in layers e.g the following screenshot?

[image]

Comment: Thanks Thomas, yes, Ideal GUI would be to use the copy past style as with layers but for a graphic object